# Products of radical bromination and mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, halogenation

My organic chemistry final is next Tuesday, and I have worked through the practice final. The last question is the following: Give and name all the compounds resulting from the radical monobromination 2,3-dimethylpentane. Indicate the major and minor products.

I drew:

[image]

My prof says that I am missing my R/S. I can clearly see my chiral centres, but how do I determine the orientation of the H? Red is the major product, blue is the minor product, and magenta is the very minor product.

The second question is: write the mechanism of this reaction identifying the initiation, propagation, and termination steps for the formation of one of the products. This is what I drew:

[image]

My prof says that I am missing a propagation step with another bromine-bromine molecule.

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My prof says that I am missing my R/S. I can clearly see my chiral centres, but how do I determine the orientation of the H? Red is the major product, blue is the minor product, and magenta is the very minor product.

You don't determine the orientation of the H you just acknowledge the formation of both the R and S stereo isomers in your products in 50/50 proportions.

> My prof says that I am missing a propagation step with another bromine-bromine molecule. I would greatly appreciate your input!

All you need to show is the organic radical reacting with diatomic bromine to form you brominated molecule and another bromine radical.

[image: Bromine Propigation]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I thought. So I simply mention the 50/50 ratio where appropriate (i.e. where there is a chiral carbon), right?

Comment: That's all.  Your starting material is chiral, and all of the products will chiral.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question: I can see it now. The molecules have either 1 or 2 chiral centres.

Comment: Not quite.  do 2-bromo-2,3-dmethylpentane and 2-bromo-3,4-dmethylpentane have 2 chiral centers or 1?

Comment: A.K. Oups! 2-bromo-2,3-dimethylpentane seems to have 1 chiral center(2), ,but  2-bromo-3,4-dimethylpentane seems to have 2 centers... Am I forgetting something? :)

Comment: No, you're good now.  I just forgot that a chiral center was formed on 2-bromo-3,4-dimethylpentane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32874/discussion-between-johnathan-and-a-k).